# creating form by using javascript for specific div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create form by using JavaScript. Then I have created code as follows. I need to add this form to 
   div id="form1"
 by using getElementsById. But it does not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form1">
</div>
    <script>
            var f = document.createElement("form");
            f.setAttribute('method',"post");
            f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

            var i = document.createElement("input");
            i.setAttribute('type',"text");
            i.setAttribute('name',"username");

            var s = document.createElement("input"); 
            s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
            s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

            f.appendChild(i);
            f.appendChild(s);

            document.getElementsById("form1")[0].appendChild(f);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its `document.getElementById` not Elements and you might want to remove the [0] from the ` document.getElementById("form1")[0].appendChild(f);

Answer (score 1):

It has to be like this:

```
document.getElementById("form1").appendChild(f);
```

This is wrong:

```
document.getElementsById("form1")[0].appendChild(f);
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/99gS2zUTTRX5Fpc3lbwD?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Here is how you can append a [table](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQRkyBL2XiK8EpH9ddUa?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you . So do you know that how to get that input data into table . the table also need to create in JavaScript.

Comment: If this helps you can accept it as answer ...this is how you can accept it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: it gives {
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "files is required",
  "validation": {
    "source": "payload",
    "keys": [
      "files"
    ]
  }
} so I need to show the table below the form.

Answer (score 0):

Change `document.getElementsById` to `document.getElementById` and take out the `[0]`.

```
<body>
<div id="form1">
</div>
<script>
        var f = document.createElement("form");
        f.setAttribute('method',"post");
        f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

        var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
        i.setAttribute('type',"text");
        i.setAttribute('name',"username");

        var s = document.createElement("input"); //input element, Submit button
        s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
        s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

        f.appendChild(i);
        f.appendChild(s);

        //and some more input elements here
        //and dont forget to add a submit button

        document.getElementById("form1").appendChild(f);
</script>
</body>
```

Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/L65fpfjj/

:)